# vb.netでTagの内容を変更できない

Tags: vb.net

vb.netでTagの内容を変更したいのですが変更できません。
最初、フォームをロードしたときにpicturebox1のtagに"1"を設定します。フォームが最初に表示されたときにはpicturebox1に1.pngが表示されています。

次にpicturebox1をクリックするとPictureBox1_Click関数内のif文の条件判定で
**If Me.PictureBox1.Tag = "1" Then**
が真と判断されてpicturebox1の画像が2.pngになります。
この時、
**Me.PictureBox1.Image.Tag = "2"**
でpicturebox1のTagに"2"を設定しているつもりなのですが、その下の
**Debug.WriteLine(Me.PictureBox1.Tag.ToString)**
では1が出力ウィンドウに出力されます。

pictureboxのTagが"1"のままなのでその後、何回クリックしても2.pngが表示されたままになります。
最初のForm1_Load関数内でtagに"1"を設定することはできるのにその後、変更できないのはなぜでしょうか？

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
        Debug.WriteLine(Me.PictureBox1.Tag.ToString) '←何回クリックしてもここは1が出力される

        If Me.PictureBox1.Tag = "1" Then
            Me.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\tada3\Desktop\自作ツール\seg\2.png")
            Me.PictureBox1.Image.Tag = "2"
            Debug.WriteLine(Me.PictureBox1.Tag.ToString)  '←ここで2が出力されてほしいが、1が出力される
        ElseIf Me.PictureBox1.Tag = "2" Then
            Me.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\tada3\Desktop\自作ツール\seg\1.png")
            Me.PictureBox1.Image.Tag = "1"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\tada3\Desktop\自作ツール\seg\1.png")
        Me.PictureBox1.Tag = "1"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

**PictureBox1.Tag**と**PictureBox1.Image.Tag**を混在しているのが原因でした。
以下の内容できちんと動作しました。

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
        Debug.WriteLine(Me.PictureBox1.Image.Tag.ToString) '←何回クリックしてもここは1が出力される

        If Me.PictureBox1.Image.Tag = "1" Then
            Me.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\tada3\Desktop\自作ツール\seg\2.png")
            Me.PictureBox1.Image.Tag = "2"
            Debug.WriteLine(Me.PictureBox1.Image.Tag.ToString)  '←ここで2が表示されてほしいが、1が表示される
        ElseIf Me.PictureBox1.image.Tag = "2" Then
            Me.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\tada3\Desktop\自作ツール\seg\1.png")
            Me.PictureBox1.Image.Tag = "1"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\tada3\Desktop\自作ツール\seg\1.png")
        Me.PictureBox1.Image.Tag = "1"
    End Sub
End Class
```

ありがとうございました。